# WIN2K8: Running two netsh commands in one line; hitting a syntax error

Tags: windows, scripting, netsh

I've written a Windows script to change NIC interface metrics, and need to condense it to two commands, because of the manner in which it is executed. To render a long story short, I support an application (BladeLogic Server Automation [BSA]) that uses remote agents to call system commands.

I've hypothesized that when BSA runs the script, each command executes in a separate Command Prompt environment, so the environment variables used to store the route strings aren't persistent.

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('netsh interface ipv4 dump ^| find "nexthop=1.1.1.1"') do @set VAR1=%a
netsh interface ipv4 set %VAR1:~4% metric=200
for /f "delims=" %a in ('netsh interface ipv4 dump ^| find "nexthop=2.2.2.1"') do @set VAR2=%a
netsh interface ipv4 set %VAR2:~4% metric=500
```

I've condensed the script as such and am testing it at the Command Prompt.

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('netsh interface ipv4 dump ^| find "nexthop=1.1.1.1"') do @set VAR1=%a && netsh interface ipv4 set %VAR1:~4% metric=200
for /f "delims=" %a in ('netsh interface ipv4 dump ^| find "nexthop=2.2.2.1"') do @set VAR2=%a && netsh interface ipv4 set %VAR2:~4% metric=500
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to recognize the proper syntax for the second command:

```
The following command was not found: interface ipv4 set %VAR1:~4% metric=200
```

Is there another way I could append the second command, so it's interpreted as being syntactically correct? I'm open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Matt,

You're correct that BladeLogic fires up separate shells for each statement, however, depending on what you're trying to achieve, it may be possible to "persuade" it to run a complete script remotely on your target.

If you're still facing this issue, please respond with a little more info about what you're trying to achieve and which approaches you've tried, and we can look a the alternatives.

-John.